# MIPS: How do I take the 5th byte of a string and replace the 4th byte of a different string with it?

Tags: string, assembly, mips

Say I have a string .asciiz "cheese", and another .asciiz "beefsteak". I want to take the 5th byte of cheese and put it where the f in beefsteak is. I can't figure this out. Here's what I have:

```
.data
string1 = .asciiz "cheese"
string2 = .asciiz "beefsteak"

.text
.globl main
main:
la $t0, string1
la $t1, string 2
add $t0, $t0, 5
add $t1, $t1, 4
lb $t1, 0($t0)
```

But this doesnt seem to work. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're close-ish except for syntax errors and forgetting the store**.

Use `string1: .asciiz "cheese"`.  `string1:` is a label exactly like `main:`, using identical syntax.  It's just in a different section.  `name = .asciiz ""` doesn't work; `=` is for defining assemble-time constants like `string1_length = . - string1`, not for assembling data bytes into memory.

`la $t1, string 2` has a space inside the symbol name which obviously doesn't work.

---

**`lb $t1, 0($t0)` destroys the `string2` pointer**.  Pick a different register for your character temporary, e.g. `lb $t0, 5($t0)` because you don't need that pointer anymore.

`lbu` would work too, but you're not going to read the full word value of the register so the choice between zero- and sign-extension doesn't matter.

You need to store your result with something like `sb $t0, 4($t1)`.

Doing `addi` at runtime is pointless for known-constant offsets: `lb` and `sb` also have a 16-bit immediate field; use it to simplify your code.  MIPS only has one addressing mode: register + imm16.  Or you could just `la` the address you want in the first place, like `la $t0, string1+5`

---

Also, the **5th byte is at `string1+4`**.  The first byte is the `c`, at `string1+0`.  So the 5th byte is the 5th letter of the word, at index 4.  Offsets are like 0-indexed C arrays.  You want `s` in `cheese`, not the final `e`.

---

Fun fact: you could also save instructions in address-generation by addressing one string relative to the other.

```
# assembles (inefficiently) with clang
# untested with MARS or GAS; pretty sure it will work at least with GAS

.data
string1: .asciiz "cheese"
string2: .asciiz "beefsteak"

.text
.globl main
main:
   la   $t0, string1
   lbu  $t1, 4($t0)                   # 5th byte = start+4 of string 1
   sb   $t1, 3+string2-string1($t0)

   jr   $ra   # return
```

This *should* assemble to 4 machine instructions (2 for `la`, or possibly only 1 if the .data section is 64k aligned.)

In practice with `clang -target mips` the `sb` assembles to `lui+addi+sb` as a pseudo-instruction, totally pointlessly.  There are no relocations on those instructions, just small constants, so a smarter assembler wouldn't have expanded `sb` as a pseudo-instruction.

`string2-string1` is a small compile-time constant, so it's fine to ask the assembler to embed it into the immediate of an `lbu` or `sb` instruction, plus some other small constant.  (If the symbols were both defined in *this* compilation unit in the same section we're fine; if they need to get filled in by the linker we'd have a problem with the subtraction.)

Even better would be if we knew the bytes were in the same 64kiB chunk and could get the assembler to emit just an `lui` into a temporary, then `lbu` and `sb` with the low part of the symbol addresses.  Using GAS `%hi(string1)` and `%low(string1) + string2-string1+3` or someething.

Or on MARS, if you ask the simulator to put the data section at a low address, you can use `lbu $t0, string1($zero)` because the full address fits in a 16-bit immediate.

Or use lbu / sb as pseudo-instructions, getting the assembler to emit `lui`+`lbu` with the lbu immediate providing the low 16 bits of the address, instead of wasting an `addiu` or `ori` generating the exact address into a register, leaving the immediate bits wasted in the actual load.

```
# tested with clang: assembles to lui+lbu,   lui+sb
   lbu $t0, string1+4
   sb  $t0, string2+3
```

This is certainly easy to write in asm source, and hard to beat for actually efficiency after expanding pseudo-instructions unless you manually take advantage of knowing that `string1` and `string2` are in the same 64k aligned region and can share an `lui`.